# how to redirect to other page when request is made using angularjs to spring controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, call, using

```
#MY Login page code snippet
--------------------------------

    <div class="login-container">
            <form ng-submit="onLogin()" name="form" class="pure-form login-form"
                ng-controller="LoginCtrl as vm">
                <fieldset class="pure-group">
                    <legend>Log In</legend>
                    <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label> <input type="text" id="inputUsername" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Username" required autofocus ng-model="vm.username">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label> <br>
                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Password" required ng-model="vm.password">
                </fieldset>

                <button type="submit"
                    class="pure-button pure-input-1 pure-button-primary">Log In</button>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</div>

            </form>
        </div>


        <div id="content" class="col-lg-10 col-sm-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box col-md-12">
                    <div class="box-inner"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


# login.js
-----------------

angular.module('loginApp', [])
        .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.onLogin = function () {

        var encodedString = '?username=' +
                    encodeURIComponent($scope.vm.username) +
                    '&password=' +
                    encodeURIComponent($scope.vm.password);             

                var url = "http://localhost:8080/servicesummary/employees/view"+encodedString;

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url                
                })
                .success(function(data) {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    var container = 'box-inner';

                    $('.' + container).html(response);  


                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    $scope.$error = 'Unable to submit form';
                })
            };

        }]);


# Spring Controller-
--------------------------

  @RequestMapping(value = "/view", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
 public ModelAndView getEmployeeInJSON(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {

            final ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
            try {
                AppUserDTO appUserdb = userService.getObject(username);

                if (null != appUserdb && (appUserdb.getPassword() != null)) {
                    String decodedPass = UtilityService.decode(appUserdb.getPassword());
                    if (decodedPass.equals(password)) {

                    System.out.println("Database Match.............");
                    mv.setViewName(VIEWNAME_HOME);
                    } else {
                        mv.setViewName(VIEWNAME_LOGIN);
                    }
                } else {
                    mv.addObject("uNameNotValid", false);
                    mv.setViewName(VIEWNAME_LOGIN);
                }    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("ERROR handleGetLogin() {}", e);
                System.out.println("Exception is occured.....");
                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/home-exception");    
            }    
            return mv;
        }
```

---

Hi i have user input username and password which i trying to validate from database using spring controller (TestController.java) from angularjs. i am bale to call controller using login.js written, but not able to process the ModelAndView object returned using angularjs. please see my login.js for reference.

Comment: An angular application typically receives JSON from the server. Not HTML. The routing should be handled at client side, based on the success or error of the received JSON response.

Comment: Does it mean i cannot return ModelAndView object.??if so then how can redirect from one page to another??..please reply.

Comment: No, you shouldn't. AngularJS applications are typically single-page applications. So you don't redirect from the server. You send a successful JSON response, the JS code gets the response, sees that it's successful and does something like `$location.url('/home')` to got to the route mapped to the `/home` url.

Comment: HI JB, i am still not able to redirect to new page. below is my js code.                  var newUrl = $location.protocol()+ "://"+ $location.host() + ":"+ $location.port() + "/servicesummary" + "/" +"underconstruction.jsp"; $location.path(newUrl).replace();.    when response coming from spring controller then i am trying to redirect to new page.

Comment: You need to understand how Angular routing works. You're not supposed to go to the URL of a JSP on the server. You shouldn't even have JSPs on the server, since all the server should do is serve JSON, and static html templates used by your angular routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your $http method as below

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url                
})
.success(function(data) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    $window.location.href = 'SuccessUrl'; 


})
.error(function(data) {
    $scope.$error = 'Unable to submit form';
})
```